# Best keyboard mapping approach to make a Mac work like Ubuntu?

Tags: macos, unix, mapping, keyboard

Through the day I work on both a Mac and Ubuntu.
What's the best option for mapping the Mac keyboard (an external, non-Mac one) to Ubuntu style keys - when using the Mac (OS X).

Basically I want to have:

<kbd>Control</kbd> on keyboard to trigger <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> keystroke on the Mac
<kbd>Alt</kbd> on keyboard to trigger <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> keystroke on the Mac
<kbd>Windows</kbd> on keyboard key to trigger <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> keystroke on the Mac

Aside from whether this is a good idea or not and which one I should pick, I am just posing the question of how to make the Mac, when used with the external keyboard, to be more Ubuntu-like.  My biggest interest is in making sure that vi/vim/macvim and tmux, both of which have a large number of keyboard commands, work the same for my fingers.

I initially thought about this posting on Ask Ubuntu but it actually seems more suitable here.

Comment: How do you intend to trigger a <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd> keystroke on the Mac?

Comment: I don't understand your concern. Other than remapping the control/command/alt/etc (modifiers), what else is different in Ubuntu? I mean, Cmd+S(ave) is going to be Control+S(ave) on Ubuntu… which is the same. Control+Tab (cmd+tab Mac)… etc. Both OS's have similar shortcuts (which you can redefine under Mac anyway). <puzzled> I use vi on a Mac (and vim) and sometimes under Linux and they are exactly the same…

Comment: @Martin, I think the point here is what the keys on the keyboard are mapped to needs to be addressed so that he can type the exact same keys and achieve the same result on either machines.

Comment: yes, just those three keys (cmnd-alt-ctrl), which have given me issues before.

Comment: What are each of those keys mapped to for the Mac currently?

Comment: It's kinda two factors I guess - one is the mapping to Ubuntu style keys (basically thew same as windows too) and/or the other is the external keyboard (actually a ms 2000 external keyboard)

Comment: Mac's not handy, I can check in a bit.

Comment: I'd say that the "biggest" difference between LInux/Windows and Mac is the CMD key being the centerpiece (instead of Control), which you should swap. Option is Alt and Windows Key is Command. But There's no "Mac" key (like Windows Key) on Mac (or "Linux" key under Linux) so by swapping Cmd<->Control you're pretty much there. Instead of CMD+C to copy, you'd press Control-C (like LInux) and the OS will be doing a CMD+C. :) Other than that… I don't see a huge difference.

Comment: Once you get the external keyboard connected, there is an approach to remapping modifier keys built right into the OS.

Comment: @ephsmith That sounds good !

Comment: @MichaelDurrant, Your answer has been posted.  All you'll need to do is (you probably already know) figure how the keys in question are recognized by MacOS and swap appropriately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, what you want to do is remap your modifiers:

Go to System Preferences and select Modifier Keys:

[image: Preferences]

Then swap Cmd and Control.

[image: Modifiers]

<sub>**note:** in the shot they are not swapped</sub>

For reference, I do this with an external Razer Blackwidow for Windows (I want it to be like my Mac keyboard because I've been using Mac keyboards for 10 years).

Comment: Yes this works well for me.  I like the fact that I have the choice and am applying it to my external keyboards only so my colleagues are not freaked out when they use the mac keyboard temporarily !

Comment: What do you do when you have a VM which inherits those Modifier changes, so when you go do CTRL+C in your VM it does CMD+C?..

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos I am not sure exactly what you mean, but the host OS determines what the action is. In the case of VMWare and Parallels, their drivers used to be "clever enough" to do the right thing (i.e.: cmd+C would do copy in the virtual OS too). But I haven't used either in a long time!

Comment: I used the key modifier settings in OSX to swap command and control, this way I can do ctrl+c for copy etc (like windows)(habits), the result was that my ubuntu VM now sees my control function attached not to the control key but to the windows duper key (so basically the keys in ubuntu also swapped).

Comment: I am quite close to switch to VMWare because its not the only issue I have with OSX and VirtualBox. The Retina screen also makes apparently the graphics slow and laggy.

Comment: About 2-3 years ago when I used all three (VMware, Parallels and VirtualBox), the first two were really faster and more advanced in terms of features than VirtualBox (but not "free"). For simple things, VirtualBox was ok (i.e.: running a simple Win XP app) but for serious stuff, I recommend trying either of the others. I liked stuff from both. I always felt Parallels was faster, yet more intrusive and buggy, but haven't used them in a while. Also Parallels tends to update every year and charge you for that, very close to subscription :) (and releases were buggy so people were unhappy). YMMV