# How can apply Ubuntu's ALT-TAB behavior to macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, desktop

I think Ubuntu's current approach to desktop window management is more efficient than macOS's.

For example, if we have 4 different workspace areas (a.k.a. Desktop in macOS world), when you do <kbd>^ Option</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, you switch only between the windows in the same workspace.

On the other hand, Mac's <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> changes between the applications, and if the same application (for example Chrome) serves in different windows, you may end up in a different mission's desktop.

So my question is how can I adopt Ubuntu's approach for macOS?

This question is not a key mapping question, I am not asking if there is a method to map the keys similarly to Ubuntu. I am asking, for a method to use <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or any other key combination ***to change windows only within the active desktop*** if that's possible.

Let me give an example. Assume the following state.

- Desktop 1: Chrome-1, Safari
- Desktop 2: Chrome-2, Firefox

When I am on Desktop 1, I want to switch only between Chrome-1 and Safari and never see Firefox and Chrome-2.

Comment: Set up alt-tab.

Comment: macOS was never designed so you could put one app on more than one Space. As soon as you do that, you break functionality. Spaces unfortunately started out well, but was broken with the introduction of fullscreen & hasn't been looked at since. The new [Stage Manager](https://support.apple.com/HT213315) was supposed to be the replacement. I'm not convinced.

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/54935/119271

Comment: Command-backtick cycles through windows of the current app. Doesn’t this work for you?

Comment: *"change windows only within the active desktop"* That's exactly what the duplicate explains. The key command [cmd/`] to switch windows *only* works in the current Space.

Comment: I think what I am asking is still different than cmd-tick methods (both from the duplicate link and from @nohillside’s suggestion).

Comment: Let me give an example. Assume following state. Desktop 1: chrome-1, safari. Desktop 2: chrome-2, firefox. When I am in desktop 1, I want to switch only between chrome 1 and safari and never see the firefox and chrome-2.

Comment: Ah, you want to switch between windows of *different* applications within *one* space? Sorry, totally missed this.

Comment: But AFAIK this is not possible without modifications/add-ons.

Comment: That's also 'half' covered by the dupe. Ctrl/F4 will march through *most* windows, without leaving the current Space… but it's too bizarrely random to rely on & stops once it thinks it's reach 'the end'. There is no other native method.

Comment: Yeah, I also guess there is no native method. But I am ok with any workaround because I think this reduce my speed (productivity).

Comment: tbh, I've always avoided this sort of thing by not putting one app on two spaces - but… for the past 25 years I've always had a desktop Mac with 2 big screens, extended keyboard & 'clever' mouse with a myriad programmable buttons. Only a month ago I got my first ever Macbook, so now I have only a tiny screen & a trackpad. Everything I do now takes three times as long. Windows are on top of windows, the trackpad is a device invented by the devil himself; it obeys gestures only when it feels like it, I've no smart mouse & no extended keyboard. Frankly, it makes me want to swear… a lot.

Comment: @Tetsujin one application per space, and keyboard combos to switch. Couldn‘t live without it :)

Comment: Yeah - I use Ctrl/[numpad] right-handed, constantly - on the lappy I have to swap hands - no numpad, only one Ctrl on the left. Drives me mad. ;) I feel like I'm trying to work with one arm tied behind me.

Comment: Ubuntu’a approach makes you think you are working N different machines.  That’s why I want the same for my Mac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, the feature you describe, although available natively on both Ubuntu and Windows, isn't available on macOS without using a third-party app. I'm therefore introducing you to:

### [AltTab on macOS](https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/)

It allows you to perform actions similar to what <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> or <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> does but AltTab ables you to switch between all opened *windows* in *current space/desktop* by using <kbd>^ Option (Alt)</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.

> [image: image from https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/ showing a preview of how AltTab works (demo)]
>
> AltTab brings the power of Windows’s “alt-tab” window switcher to macOS.

By default, AltTab will switch between windows *across all spaces* when you press <kbd>^ Option (Alt)</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>. To have it only switch between windows in *current space*, you have to open AltTab's preferences, and in the *Controls* tab, for "Show windows from:", select "*Active Space*".