# Selectively disable cmd+tab (while in Microsoft Remote Desktop)

Tags: macos, mac, windows, remote-control

Is there a way to selectively disable a global shortcut? I would like to use 'alt'+tab on my remote win machine to switch apps, but it seems to be always overridden by cmd+tab which I use to switch apps on mac OS. I do not think that it can be done in Mac OS itself, is there a way to do it with Karabinier?

Comment: What are you actually pressing to send alt/tab?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can apply Ubuntu's ALT-TAB behavior to macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/457564/how-can-apply-ubuntus-alt-tab-behavior-to-macos)

Comment: What happens exactly when you press Alt-Tab in Microsoft Remote Desktop? I use the app regularly and Alt-Tab works as expected, that is, it switches Windows apps just fine. Command-Tab works as expected too: it switches macOS apps only. I have version 10.8.4 (2111) installed, which is the latest release from the App Store.